# Gdevelop - iOS does not open URLs

Tags: ios, url, mobile

Good Morning,

I've noticed that when I publish my app on iOS, it can't open the links. I have social media links (to try to open the app or the browser) and links that require the browser because it is a website.

Apparently they don't work for iOS and there aren't many options to open the links. Does the URL have to contain a specific format?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1d5K.png)

Thank you!